# How Functions can be called from java enum?

Tags: java, spring, enums, functional-programming

I'm trying to understand how the static method calls from a Java enum works.

To see the full code of this ["Working example"](https://github.com/RJansenGomez/Springboot-Mongo-example/tree/main/src/main/java/org/rjansen/common/repository)

I have the following scenario working, I don't know why

```
public enum Condition {
    GREATER_THAN(PredicateBuilder::generateGreaterThan, ">"),
    more values...
    private Condition(BiFunction<PredicateBuilder, PredicateContent<?>, Predicate> predicate, String operator) {
        this.operator = operator;
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }
```

This is the predicate builder, it's an interface implemented by a @Component from Spring:

```
@Component
public class PredicateLogicalBuilder<V extends Comparable> implements PredicateBuilder<V> {

    @Override
    public Predicate generateGreaterThan(PredicateContent<V> predicateContent) {
        return predicateConversion(predicateContent,Condition.GREATER_THAN);
    }
}
```

The static reference in above Condition enum doesn't complain about:

```
Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context
```

and I don't why because now I'm trying to do something similar and it fails because the static reference of a method isn't static. In the code above is not static either.

Code I'm trying:

```
public interface MethodCalls<T> {
    void randomMethod(T content);
}

@Component
public class TestEnumMethoCalls implements MethodCalls<SomeBean> {
    @Override
    public void randomMethod(SomeBean content){
        System.out.println("Works!!!!");
    }
}

public enum NotificationType {
    ENUM_TEST_1(MethodCalls::randomMethod);

    public final Function<SomeBean,Void> method;

    private NotificationType(Function<SomeBean,Void> method){
       this.method=method;
    }
}

public class TestClass{
    public void testMethtod(){
        NotificationType.ENUM_TEST_1.method.apply(new SomeBean())
    }
}
```

This piece of code fails saying the `Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context`:

```
ENUM_TEST_1(MethodCalls::randomMethod);
```

I would like to have 2 answers:

- Why the code of the "Working example" works.
- If it's mandatory for my current test to use the instance of the `MethodCalls` how can be injected with DI to the enum (is a static context so I understand it might be tricky if not impossible).

Comment: So I cant be sure, but I dont see how Java can work out which implementation of `MethodCalls` should be used in `ENUM_TEST_1(MethodCalls::randomMethod)`. Also as it stands `MethodCalls::randomMethod` is a static call, i.e. `MethodCalls.randomMethod(x)` and no static method exists in the interface, hence the error.  I think `new TestEnumMethoCalls().randomMethod(x)` might work though you will need a value for x.  It is likely that the Spring version works as Spring is able to figure out what implementation to inject.

Comment: `randomMethod` would have to be static since you are not passing "this" instance with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help, now I understood why my "working example" works and how to "Fix" my current issue:

To fix it I have to pass an instance of the implementation of the interface as it's pointed out that enums can only access static methods or an instance of the object to access the method that way.

Final Code

```
public enum NotificationType {
    ENUM_TEST_1(MethodCalls::randomMethod);

    public final BiFunction<MethodCalls,SomeBean,Void> method;

    private NotificationType(BiFunction<MethodCalls,SomeBean,Void> method){
        this.method=method;
    }
}
```

So when I call the apply it looks like this:

```
public class TestClass{
    @Autowired MethodCalls methodCalls;
    public void testMethtod(){
        NotificationType.ENUM_TEST_1.method.apply(methodCalls,new SomeBean())
    }
}
```

I someone finds out a cleaner way to do this, I would apreciate it.